# How do I connect mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm tryna connect to mongodb through python but it's kinda different from javascript so its not working, please someone help a bit?

```
db = MongoClient.connect("mongodb://host:port") # Changed that in the real code to my own server which workes

collection = db.test_db
```

Answer (score 0):

Python syntax is different from JavaScript, and might get some new coders confused...

Try this instead:

```
mongodb = MongoClient("mongodb://host:port")
db = mongodb["db_name"]
col = db["collection_name"]
```